# How to share app development between two companies with hidden code?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, webview

So basically, we want to co-create Android and iOS app with a partner company.

Today, company A has their own mobile app running, and when clicking a button inside the app, it opens the browser and shows the screens/module created by company B.

The goal is to embed it together in the same app, but without company B sharing its code with company A. Company B uses ionic and some native functionalities.

Webview doesn't work as expected with webRTC and other native functionalities, so its not really an option.

Thanks.

Comment: "Company A" App is Native in Java/Kotlin or made in Ionic?

Comment: Company B can _probably_ create an android library (AAR) and provide it. Company A can implement the library just like any other dependency. However I am not sure if Ionic allow to easily create an android library.